Metamask connect button not working on IOS 18
Working on a dApp and have a button connect wallet. Was working properly until I updated to IOS 18.
Expected behavior: user clicks connect wallet -> asks to open metamask -> on metamask asks to connect account to the website -> return to the website
Actual behavior: user clicks connect wallet -> asks to open metamask -> opens metamask and does nothing
-btw works fine on both desktop and android-
useEffect(() => {
    if (walletId) {
      onWalletConnected(walletId);
    }
  }, [walletId, onWalletConnected]);

  const connect = async () => {
    try {
      const accounts = await sdk?.connect();
      if (accounts && accounts.length > 0) {
        const account = accounts[0];
        setWalletId(account);
        showToast('Wallet connected successfully');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to connect:', err);
    }
  };

